# Android Installation Error

Tags: android

I installed android in my new laptop. I keep getting the below error whenever I try open the "Android SDK and AVD manager" from the Window drag down menu in Eclipse IDE.

[image: I have already set the android sdk path in preferences but I still get the error every time when I open the manager.]

I have already set the path in the preferences of eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to Eclipse's Preferences, and click on the Android subheading on the left, there should be an SDK Location preference. 
Click the Browse... button, and select the *root* folder of the Android SDK install location. This should point to the folder that houses the add-ons/, docs/, and tools/ folders among others.

If eclipse is still giving you the same error, try [redownloading and uncompressing](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) the SDK for your platform, and pointing Eclipse to the folder using the instructions above.

Comment: extremely sorry for the late reply. I re-installed the android SDK but I keep getting same error whenever I open Eclipse IDE.

Comment: @mospled This problem does occur after I again reinstalled the android SDK.